# Bootstrap columns not aligned properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I am making a twitter clone using RubyOnRails and bootstrap as the framework. When trying to distribute some text in a post panel using the "col-sm" div class, the text seems jammed together on the left,
[as seen here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa41c.png)

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-body">
            <p>status</p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-body">
            <p>trend</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-6">
      <%= render '/components/post_form' %><br></br>

      <% for @p in @posts %>
         <div class="panel panel-default post-panel">
            <div class="panel-body">
               <div class="col-sm-1">
                  AVATAR
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-11">
                  <p><%= @p.content %></p>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-12">
                  LINKS
               </div>

            </div>
         </div>
      <% end %>

   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-body">
            <p>about</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I am using the latest bootstrap sass version 3.3.6 which is included in the gemfile. Is there something wrong with the code or does the latest version of bootstrap mean I need to do something different?

Comment: Paste your rendered page into this tool http://www.bootlint.com/#byDirect and resolve the errors.  It should fix the problems.  I think the issue is columns are supposed to be inside rows and all rows need to be inside containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this section:

```
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      AVATAR
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-11">
      <p><%= @p.content %></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      LINKS
    </div>
```

The first issue is the text "AVATAR" is wider than 1 bootstrap column, so it's extending out of your container. using `col-sm-2`/`col-sm-10` may fix the issue.

Second, column sizes should add up to 12 columns per row. Here you have a `col-sm-1`, `col-sm-11`, and `col-sm-12` all in the same row.

Comment: Awesome, didn't know that. But the tutorial that I'm following has the text in unique places e.g. the link and content is roughly center and the avatar is on the left. How do I know big to make each row in order to align them in a specific location?

Comment: Sorry, I managed to sought it out! Thank you for your help :)